# PowerShell: HTTP Response Code is missing following a POST (small load test)

Tags: powershell, loops, http, foreach

Gurus, I am 99% of the way there in my code which is a PowerShell script that does an HTTP POST.  In it, I am attempting to print to console the HTTP response code from a web server which resides on a Layer 7 API-GW (a Layer 7 API-GW has a web server on top of a hardened Linux server) - this is not IIS.  I understand the drawbacks of doing an HTTP POST by drawing the entire file in memory as I am doing below; I am not worried about that - my load test is small and terminates after 30 HTTP POSTs.  My question is, why is it not printing out the HTTP response code from the server?  It is getting an answer, but shows a blank in the PowerShell console window rather than the response code.

```
$FilePath = 'D:\Scripts\AVTest\Clean Files\AssetHandbook.pdf';
#Symantec:
$URL = 'https://labserver1.dev.local:8443/Scanfile/test';
#Sophos:
$fileBytes = [System.IO.File]::ReadAllBytes($FilePath);
# $fileEnc = [System.Text.Encoding]::GetEncoding('UTF-8').GetString($fileBytes);
$fileEnc = ([System.Text.Encoding]::GetEncoding("ISO-8859-1").GetString($fileBytes));
$boundary = [System.Guid]::NewGuid().ToString();
$LF = "`r`n";
$bodyLines = (
    "--$boundary",
    "Content-Disposition: form-data; name=`"file`"; filename=`"AssetHandbook.pdf`"",
    "Content-Type: application/octet-stream$LF",
    $fileEnc,
    "--$boundary--$LF"
) -join $LF
$SC = "";
 
$i=1
Do{
    Try{
        $SC=(Invoke-RestMethod -Uri $URL -Method Post -ContentType "multipart/form-data; boundary=`"$boundary`"" -Body $bodyLines).StatusCode
    }
    catch{
        $SC=($_.Exception.Response.StatusCode.value__)
    }
        
    Write-host($SC) -ForegroundColor Red -BackgroundColor Cyan
    $clipboard = $SC
    $i++
}
Until($SC -eq 429 -or $i -gt 30)
 
Set-Clipboard $clipboard
Start-Sleep -Second 1
Write-host $SC "<----- HTTP Status code" -ForegroundColor Red -BackgroundColor Cyan
```

Below screenshot is from a different script which does an HTTP GET.  This is kind of what I am expecting to see:

[image]

Using my current script posted above and which does an HTTP POST, this is what I see instead:
[image]

Comment: According to the docs, possible return types of `Invoke-RestMethod` include `System.Int64`, `System.String`, `System.Xml.XmlDocument`. None of these include a `StatusCode` member. If you can use PS 7, there is parameter `-StatusCodeVariable` though.

Comment: @zett42 - Thanks for the heads up.  That said, I wound up keying instead on a specific JSON response from the remote server to do what I needed to do.   If you write up your comment as an "Answer", I'll accept.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/invoke-restmethod?view=powershell-7.2#outputs), possible output types of `Invoke-RestMethod` include `System.Int64`, `System.String`, `System.Xml.XmlDocument`. None of these include a `StatusCode` member.

If you can use PS 7, there is [parameter](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/invoke-restmethod?view=powershell-7.2#parameters) `-StatusCodeVariable` though. When this parameter is passed, the cmdlet sets the given variable to the HTTP status code after return.